# ¿Comó restringir el acceso por URL a una página?

Tags: php, javascript, xampp

Tengo un login sencillo en JavaScript que redirige a un página específica. Valida los datos del "usuario", pero si ingreso la URL de la página a la que redirige el login me deja ingresar.

La pregunta es: ¿Como evitar que un "usuario" salte el protocolo de seguridad "login" e ingrese por url directamente?

Este es el código javascript que tengo por ahora:

```
class User{
    constructor(nickname, password){
        this.nickname = nickname;
        this.password = password;
    }
};
var user = new User("Usuario", "contraseña");
var nickname = document.getElementById('nickname');
var password = document.getElementById('password');
var submit = false;

var loginButton = document.getElementById('sign-in');
loginButton.addEventListener('click', signIn);

function signIn(){

    let userNickname = nickname.value;
    let userPass = password.value;

    if (userNickname == user.nickname && userPass == user.password) {
        location.href = "http://127.0.0.1/sirevo/views/admin/index.php";
    }else{
        swal(
          'Usuario o contraseña invalidos',
          'No se pudo iniciar sesión',
          'error'
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: Puedes usar PHP para validar la sesión del usuario y en caso de que esta no exista redirigir a la página de login, la manera más sencilla sería revisar tus variables de sesión si estas ya cuentan con información.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, la verdad no conozco muy bien php, pero con una pequeña guía creo que puedo lograrlo...

Comment: Esta es la guía de W3 schools de sessiones en PHP: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp  y esta una implementación de lo que ocuparías: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545357/how-to-check-if-a-user-is-logged-in-in-php, pero ya estamos hablando de usar bases de datos, cadenas de conexión y otros elementos más avanzados que simple JS.

Comment: Bueno es algo que aún no se hacer... no habría forma de simular el o los usuarios con variables y simplemente enviar un error si tratan de ingresar por url???

Comment: Hola, he investigado un poco y he practicado con php. Incluso creo que he resuelto el problema, (Bueno hasta cierto punto "teniendo en cuenta que no creo que sea un login impenetrable").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es seguro validar un inicio de session con javascript o del lado del cliente, esto puede facilmente ser hackeado. Te recomiendo que uses un lemguaje del lado del servidor para validar inicios de sesion o realizarlo,  y por tu pregunta si si se puede ver si un usuario ingresa directamemte a una url, como? Usando document.referrer. ,no te recomiemdo hacerlo pero bueno

```
if(document.referrer == location.href){
      location.href = 'error.php';
}
```

lo que hace esta linea de codigo es verrificar si la url tiene una provinencia, osea que haya sido traida por una redireccion o un enlance, pero como te dije presenta varios incovenientes y muchas debilidades unas de ellas es que cualquiera puede crear un link que te mande a esa locacion, otra que creo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente

```
if(document.referrrer !== 'https://yourweb.com/url-de-tu-login'){
    location.href == 'error.php';
}
```

creo que ahi habria mas seguridad, y lo qu hace el codigo es comprobar si el usuario ingreso a la pagina desde una redireccion del login, sino te enviara a error.php